# What happens when a land attacks then stops being a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Nature's Revolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNature%27s%5d%2b%5bRevolt%5d) is out, then a mountain and is declared as an attacker, then the enchantment is destroyed.

What happens to the mountain? Is it still attacking, can it be blocked e.t.c.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The mountain will be removed from combat; which means it stops attacking, blocking, etc.

> 506.4. A permanent is removed from combat if it leaves the battlefield, if its controller changes, if it phases out, if an effect specifically removes it from combat, if it’s a planeswalker that’s being attacked and stops being a planeswalker, or if it’s an attacking or blocking creature that regenerates (see rule 701.14) **or stops being a creature.** **A creature that’s removed from combat stops being an attacking, blocking, blocked, and/or unblocked creature.** A planeswalker that’s removed from combat stops being attacked.

Comment: Question has been edited by the asker. Please edit your response to accomodate the edits, as this one is no longer relevant to the question

Comment: I feel like changes the question enough that it should be asked as a separate question; and this one rolled back....

Comment: Hmmmmm.... Probably true. Even so, shouldn't you still get rid of the answer if it is no longer relevant to the existing question?

Comment: Since the question was edited so soon after asking; I've just gone ahead and updated my answer to answer the new question.

Comment: Seems fair enough :D

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the card can be blocked. The card would count as a creature, that in this situation, is attacking. Unless you decided to enchant it or use a spell that causes otherwise, the land *would* be able to be blocked, as well as block.

Comment: I think maybe you missed the part of the question where the Nature's Revolt, which is making the land a creature in the first place, is destroyed after attackers are declared.

Comment: The idea of the question is that the land STOPS being a creature before blockers are declared. Could you maybe consider editing or deleting this answer due to irrelevancy?